# Problem Navigating from Fragment to another Fragment (android)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm currently devoloping an app, in which there is a FirstFragment, where the user can complete Tasks, and a Settings Fragment called action_settings. Ive created an Appbar (3 dots in the top left) and added an if statement to check if the "settings" Option was selected. Now i have trouble navigating from the one Fragment to the other.
There is also another fragment, called second_fragment. I navigate to it everytime the user finished a set of tasks, to show him the results. here is how i usually do that:

```
private void finish(boolean failed, int questionsCorrect, int questionsWrong, int score){
                started = false;
                FirstFragmentDirections.ActionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(failed,questionsCorrect,questionsWrong,score);
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(action);

}
```

and here is the xml code for it in nav_graph.xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.testapp1.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SecondFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_action_settings"
            app:destination="@id/action_settings" />
    </fragment>
```

and

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.testapp1.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="failed"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <argument
            android:name="questionsCorrect"
            app:argType="integer" />
        <argument
            android:name="questionsWrong"
            app:argType="integer" />
        <argument
            android:name="score"
            app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>
```

i transfer a few variables. Also my nav_graph looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt1J8.png).

There are actions going firstfragment to second and settings, and actions from second and settings to first fragment.

Now here is my problem. I wanna navigate from First Fragment to Settings, when a Option in the Action bar is selected. it looks like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            System.out.println("Test");


            return true;
        }
```

Ive tested it, whenever i click the option it prints "test" to the console.

But when trying to insert similar code to what i did when i navigated from first fragment to second fragment, it throws an error:

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            FirstFragmentDirections.ActionFirstFragmentToActionSettings action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToActionSettings(1);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(action);




            return true;
        }
```

(this is in MainActivity.java)
Error:
'com.example.testapp1.FirstFragment' is not an enclosing class

and i dont know how to fix it. Is there any other way i can navigate to another fragment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your action bar on the activity or on the FirstFragment itself ?

Comment: Its in the activity.